# Upgrading to DXA Java 1.4

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java

When upgrading from an earlier release of DXA to DXA 1.4 (Java) are there any changes on the CMS side or just the DXA libraries and web application? I am asking this since we have a lot of custom content types created and I am not sure how any CMS side update would affect those.

We are running SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#2 with Oracle as the CM & CD database.

Comment: Which earlier version of DXA?

Comment: We were running the pre-release Java build of DXA however at one point we tried upgrading. On the presentation side we are still on the pre-release but not sure about the CM side. Is there a way to check the DB version to know which version os DXA is it running? I checked the TDS_DB_INFO table but that doesn't have any info on DXA. It just says 7.1.0.1 (SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1).

Comment: You can check the version number field in the DXA Core Configuration Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "the pre-release Java build of DXA" means the pre-release version that was made available before the official release of DXA 1.2 Java: yes, there were for sure CM-side changes.

However, you don't have to be scared of CM-side updates; upgrading the DXA CM items should be quite straight-forward using the provided cms-import.ps1 PowerShell scripts; I'm not expecting impact on "custom content types".

Comment: Thank you Rick. Yes I am referring to the releases made available prior to official DXA Java release. Looking at the DXA Core Config component I found the version number to be 1.1